# Check whether the interpreter is embedded

Tags: python, c++, c

I'm creating Python binary *module* using Python C API. Also I'm creating a separate *program* which uses Python C API and runs some python scripts where the *module* might be used. 
The question is **how to check (using Python C API) whether my *module* is loaded inside default python interpreter either inside my *program*?** I don't consider using global static variables in my module because of my program must not know about this module anything.
Now I use Py_SetProgramName function in my program:

```
Py_SetProgramName("myprogram");
```

And check it inside my module:

```
bool isEmbedded = Py_GetProgramName() == std::string("myprogram");
```

It works fine, but I don't like this way as well. Are there any other approaches to solve this issue?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why does this matter?

Comment: This question is tagged C, but you go and use `std::string`...

Comment: @ignacio-vazquez-abrams enterprise developing :) Inside program environment more features than outside.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't try to check. What I would do is have the embedding program either create a virtual module that contains the additional functionality, with the external module attempting to import this module and monkeypatching itself, or have it contain functions that the module will attempt to load and then call via function pointers. If the internal module fails to import or the functions fail to be loaded then the additional functionality will be unavailable and the module will run in a reduced-capability manner.

Comment: Nice thought, but I need to have at least two python front-ends -- my program and an original python interpreter and the single back-end -- my module. That's obligatory.

Comment: Yes. And your module tries to pull additional functionality from the executable. If it can't, i.e. it's running under the Python executable or some other executable that doesn't provide this functionality, then it will have to do without.

Comment: Makes sense. It might solve my issue as Py_GetProgramName does :) I'm looking for more pythonic approach. I can do that in few ways, but they're more complex.

Comment: You have a complex problem to begin with. And Python provides no solution for it.

Comment: @Ivanll'in How is "inject module into python from host, check in python for module" not a pythonic approach?